# where is validate the password of wallet, in blockchain itself or in another application?

Tags: request, cryptography, blockchain

I and my friends are building one Blockchain for technology fair in our college(INATEL) and we hit in a problem.

Where do we validate the password of wallet, in blockchain itself or in another application? 
Is it possible to change the code of blockchain  (in Bitcoin for example) and enter in the network? If the validation is made in the blockchain the password will be received in the body and "bad node" can save the password in your database and pass to another person?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some fundamental misconceptions on how the Bitcoin network functions here.

To begin with, from the blockchain's point of view, there is no such thing as a password. Passwords on wallets are a purely wallet-added function, usually to safeguard the private keys associated with an address.

When you enter a password into the wallet, your private keys are decrypted locally on that device. Those keys are then used to sign a transaction, and the signed transaction is broadcasted to various nodes in the Bitcoin network. The password is irrelevant to the transaction, beyond unlocking the private keys needed to sign it.

If you have a signed transaction, all you can do is verify that the signature is valid. You cannot alter it if you do not have the private key. Due to this, a malicious node cannot store a password or key, since they never receive those things.